# How to insert random number in one go in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Please consider below procedure

```
begin
for i in 0..99
loop
insert into cx_vf_Test_ids values (100+i,'STB','N');
end loop;
commit;
end;
```

It will insert 100 values sequentially from 100 to 199 and for every value 'STB' and 'N' will remain same.

My requirement is to insert random values which i am getting from my team for example
101,187,193,138,189...... in this case I am having only 100 values and STB and N will remain same

Please give your suggestion.

Comment: Are duplicates allowed?

Comment: "random values which i am getting from my team" - so how are they random? And are you still getting all 100 values (from 100 to 199) just in a random order, which is irrelevant as the database won't store them in the order they're inserted? Or will there be numbers outside that range, and/or gaps and duplicates?

Comment: I have 89441000300300020009,894410003003000200017,89441000300300020003, 89441000300300020012 like this i have total 100 no that i am getting from my team in a text file so only those number written in file i need to insert only those and every 2 days i am getting this file containing new 100 number and again need to insert that file. do you have any solution

Answer (score 0):

```
create table temp
(
num number(4),
varc varchar(5),
varc1 varchar (5))
;
begin
for i in 0..99
loop
insert into temp values (trunc(dbms_random.value(100,199)),'STB','N');
end loop;
end;
```

Output: `select * from temp;`

```
109 STB N
163 STB N
169 STB N
137 STB N
145 STB N
184 STB N
107 STB N
```

So you must did something wrong. It works perfectly in my SQLDev.

Comment: Hi Michal, Thank you for your suggestion but I want to insert numer what I have now like 89441000300300020009,894410003003000200017,89441000300300020003

Comment: So Michal's random numbers weren't the random numbers you were looking for? What does "like 89441000300300020009,894410003003000200017,89441000300300020003" mean? Once you've defined the requirement we can get on to the "in one go in SQL" part.

Comment: Edits has been made

Comment: I have 89441000300300020009,894410003003000200017,89441000300300020003, 89441000300300020012 like this i have total 100 no that i am getting from my team in a text file so only those number written in file i need to insert only those and every 2 days i am getting this file containing new 100 number and again need to insert that file. do you have any solution

Answer (score 0):

Get your team to insert the "random" values into a table and then make an insert-select. E.g. this way:

```
create table so58a_t (num number);

insert into so58a_t values (101);
insert into so58a_t values (187);
insert into so58a_t values (193);
insert into so58a_t values (138);
insert into so58a_t values (189);

create table so58b_t (num number, foo varchar2(10), bar varchar2(10));

insert into so58b_t(num, foo, bar)
select
 100 + num
,'STB'
,'N'
from so58a_t;
```

Yields a result:

```
select * from so58b_t order by num;

       NUM FOO        BAR
---------- ---------- ----------
       201 STB        N
       238 STB        N
       287 STB        N
       289 STB        N
       293 STB        N
```

Table can also be an *external table*.

Comment: I have 89441000300300020009,894410003003000200017,89441000300300020003, 89441000300300020012 like this i have total 100 no that i am getting from my team in a text file so only those number written in file i need to insert only those and every 2 days i am getting this file containing new 100 number and again need to insert that file. do you have any solution

Comment: @RshiKant Yes I have. First option is to import the number values from a text file to a database table (e.g. with SQL Developer). This case you can apply the solution above. Second option is to use _external table_ (use your google-fu for the details) when loading the numbers to database.

Comment: Please explain the second option

Answer (score 0):

Example to generate a random number witout decimals:

```
DECLARE
    N NUMBER;
BEGIN
    N := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(100, 199);
    --Number without deimals 
    N := TRUNC(N, 0);
    -- Print output on screen
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(N);
END;
/
```

Comment: I have 89441000300300020009,894410003003000200017,89441000300300020003, 89441000300300020012 like this i have total 100 no that i am getting from my team in a text file so only those number written in file i need to insert only those and every 2 days i am getting this file containing new 100 number and again need to insert that file. do you have any solution